# How to display an ember.js model/RecordArray updated from the Controller?

Tags: ember.js

I'm generating a RecordArray, a subset of the model, inside the controller, but I don't know how to display it with handlebars `{{#each}}` in the html.

The answers below might also show how to display in ember.js 2/multiple models in the same controller in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

So lets say ItemsController has a list of items but you just want to list the special items in your template. Add a computed property that filters the items like this:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  specialItems: function() {
    var items = this.get('content');
    return items.filterProperty('isSpecial')
  }.property('content.@each.isSpecial');
});
```

Then reference that property in your template:

```
{{#each item in specialItems}}
  {{item.title}}
  ... 
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to first set a variable with the controller that contains the RecordArray. Then you can call `each` on that variable.

```
App.YourController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  ...
  doSearch: function(){
      var theRecordArray = App.Model.find({theAttribute: blah});
      this.set('variableOfYourChoice', theRecordArray);
  }
});
```

And in the html:

```
{{#each variableOfYourChoice}}
  <li>{{theAttribute}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

See it running in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/360/edit) which shows the RecordArray as search results.